# Doctrine2 ManyToMany with additional attribute

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I used to manipulate databases, I would like to create under Symfony2/Doctrine2 a ManyToMany model with attribute createdAt, for a model about favorite posts.

Here is my current code

A User Entity with :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="favorite")
*/
private $favorites;
```

and a Post Entity with :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="favorites")
*/
private $users;
```

I have a table *favorite(post_id, user_id)* which is created.

How can I create a table *favorite(post_id, user_id, createdAt)* ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You would do this by creating an one-to-many-to-one relationship and creating your own entity in the middle

In the User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserFavorites", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $userFavorites;
```

Do the same for Post entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserFavorites", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $userFavorites;
```

create a UserFavorites entity to connect the 2:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="userFavorites")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="userFavorites")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $post;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;
```